# Java questions tagged as Android on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There are lots of questions tagged [android](/questions/tagged/android), when in fact the question is about Java and have nothing to do with Android ([recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186491/java-front-back-a-string)). It's seems obvious that such questions should be retagged as "Java", but should "Android" tag be removed from such question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I usually add the Java tag and keep the Android tag intact. The Java API offered by [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) does namely not cover the *entire* [Java SE API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) (and from the other side on, Android has some additional APIs like HttpClient which is not provided by Java SE). This helps the answerers to realize that and take into account when answering. It also makes it easier for others to search for Android specific solutions.

However, in *this particular* question, no other API than the basic `java.lang` API is necessary to bake a valid answer for, which is present in both Android and Java SE APIs, so it's relatively safe to remove the Android tag.

It has to be determined on per-question basis, having the knowledge of both the Java SE and Android APIs back in mind.

Comment: +1, that's a very good point I did not consider.

Comment: +1, i didn't consider it as well

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that since it doesn't actually have anything to do with Android (specifically), remove the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag.  It's just a question about how to do something in Java =)

Comment: FYI, I went ahead and did this (added Java, removed Android)

Comment: +1. I didn't retag this question just to keep it as example for some time =)

Comment: @Vladimir That makes sense.  I really need to think things through more, sorry about that!

Comment: it's okay, the previous tags can always be seen in revision history =)

Answer (score 0):

You can always just suggest the edit to remove the tag Android and add the tag Java and other users will review the edit and make a decision as well. If they feel it is an invalid edit then it will be rejected, no harm to you. I don't particularly see how the post is related to Android.